# Interpretting Ng perron Unit Root Statistics

Tags: time-series, unit-root

i have applied NG Perron's modified tests to my timer series data. But when I tried to interpret test statistics I saw that, decision given by MZa and MAzt contradicts with MSB and MPT.

Is there an assumption which I should know, that would cause thise diversion

Thanks..

[image: Test Results]